# Is "== true" nessecary here?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, boolean

Real quick question: I used to do Java, and I know that if you were using an "if statement" to test if a boolean variable was true, you could say `if ( x == true )`, or just shorten it to `if ( x )`. My question is, I am using JavaScript to see if a radio button is checked, and I want to know if it needs to say `if ( document.getElementById("x").checked == true )` or if I can just say `if ( document.getElementById("x").checked )`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Either way will work, at the end of the day, if it is radio button is checked the returned value will be `true` so the `if` statement will be a boolean check.

Comment: It checks if it's equal to true, or if it's a truth value

Answer (score 0):

Both will work, so it makes more sense to use the one with less code.

Therefore:

```
if (document.getElementById("x").checked) //do something
```

The if statement is just looking to evaluate true or false. If whatever is inside the brackets returns true, it will execute the code. Therefore if you did the following:

`if (!document.getElementById("x").checked) //do something`

In this scenario, if the element is not checked, the statement returns true and executes the code.